# How to use recovery mnemonic in metamask to import account instead of private key?

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask, dapp-development, authentication

We can import account by importing private key of the account. While creating a new account we give passphrase to encrypt the private key. How to import an account in metamask using the mnemonic?

Comment: By using the passphrase, do you mean the mnemonic, or the UTC/keystore file that is encrypted with a passphrase?

Comment: Yes, I mean mnemonic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Importing a mnemonic can only be done when you are not logged in. It's best to backup any existing accounts in the current MetaMask instance before importing a mnemonic.

When logged out, you can click `Restore from seed phrase`, right under the `Login` button. There, enter your seed phrase and set a password.

Check out [this tutorial](https://medium.com/publicaio/how-import-a-wallet-to-your-metamask-account-dcaba25e558d)